# csv file reading wrong value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that reading CSV file into the record set:

Here is the major part:

```
conn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
         "Data Source=" & Sheets("Reference").Range("DataSource").Value & ";" & _
         "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
strSQL = "Select * from file.csv"
rsFutures.Open strSQL, conn

 vTemp = rsFutures("Start /Index")
 If Not IsNull(vTemp) Then cells(1,1) = vTemp
```

I have a problem, the value 3S6S in the file, recordset has as 36???!!!!
How that happening?

All ideas is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: on what line number in the file does that occur? What do the lines from line 0 - 20 look like for that column in the file?

Comment: First 20 records for that field are empty, so it is starting from 23rd line. Does it matter?

Comment: Unless you specify the column's data type it will make a guess based on the first ~20 lines. It might have guessed an integer when it should be string and discarded all the non-numeric characters. Step into the recordset when you get the error and look at the datatype on that column. Maybe, try putting an empty string, `""`, or some letters in the first line.

Comment: thanks Brad, I will try tomorrow and update the question. How can I specify the column data type? if I access it using rs and field name ?

Comment: Brad, I checked type of recordset field and it is saying that this is a currency. Not sure how recordset takes this out of the file? I checked other fields with empty values as well and all others defined right as chars.

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out how it lands on a specific datatype when there is no information to guess by. But, obviously currency will not allow for non-numeric characters. I get around this sometimes by, instead of having `,,,` literally nothing between my commas put this in your raw file at the top line `"","","",` It should see that that column in a string type. See how that goes.

Comment: Brad, thanks a lot for your tips, I was able to solve the problem using Schema.ini file. But your idea to find out column type was very handy !!!

Comment: well done, the schema.ini is a good solution

Comment: FYI You can post an answer to your own question to benefit other in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyone who might have similar problem in the future, the solution for me was creation of the Schema.ini file which took care of record set column types right away. Here is the small sample:

```
[myfile.csv] 
Format=CSVDelimited 
ColNameHeader=True 
Col1=TR Char Width 255 
Col2=Book Char Width 255 
... 
ColN=Comment Char Width 255
CharacterSet=ANSI
```

just save it in the same folder you export (or save) csv file into.
Good Luck.

p.s. Thanks Brad